# Why does the following code for conversion of flattened dictionary to nested dictionary work?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am coming from JavaScript background and for the life of me, I cant understand why this python code example from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-flattened-dictionary-into-nested-dictionary/) works.

Input Data:

```
{'Geeks_for_for':1,'for_geeks_Geeks':3,'geeks_Geeks_for':7}
```

Output:

```
{'Geeks': {'for': {'for': 1}}, 'for': {'geeks': {'Geeks': 3}}, 'geeks': {'Geeks': {'for': 7}}}
```

Code:

```
def insert(dct, lst):
    for x in lst[:-2]:
        dct[x] = dct = dct.get(x, dict())
        print(x)
        print(dct)
    dct.update({lst[-2]: lst[-1]})
    print("---######---")
    print(dct)

def convert_nested(dct):
    result = dict()
    lsts = [[*k.split("_"), v] for k, v in dct.items()]
    for lst in lsts:
        insert(result, lst)
    print(result)

ini={'Geeks_for_for':1,'for_geeks_Geeks':3,'geeks_Geeks_for':7}
convert_nested(ini)
```

Output printed:

```
Geeks
{}
for
{}
---######---
{'for': 1}
for
{}
geeks
{}
---######---
{'Geeks': 3}
geeks
{}
Geeks
{}
---######---
{'for': 7}
{'Geeks': {'for': {'for': 1}}, 'for': {'geeks': {'Geeks': 3}}, 'geeks': {'Geeks': {'for': 7}}}
```

What I understand is, dct[x] = dct = dct.get(x, dict()) initializes empty values to keys (like using try catch to 'assign' empty values). But at the same time it also destroys the dct object. So how is it preserved? Or is it like, python only allows alterations to the dictionary values but not destruction of keys? If that makes sense :(.
Can someone please give me a line by line explanation for the 2 lines of insert function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python assigns from left to right, so

```
dct[x] = dct = dct.get(x, dict())
```

is like

```
subdict = dct.get(x, dict())  # get subdict or new one when missing
dct[x] = subdict              # save subdict (needed only when missing)
dct = subdict                 # continue with the subdict
```

except without extra variable. It's in my opinion a silly way to write

```
dct = dct.setdefault(x, {})
```

And `dct.update({lst[-2]: lst[-1]})` is an in my opinion silly way to write `dct[lst[-2]] = lst[-1]`.

Well that's what you get for trying to learn Python from the in my experience horrible geeksforgeeks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Due to not having 15 reputation I can't accept or upvote it. On a different note, which website as per your opinoin has the highest quality of python learning resources? I dont mind it being extra difficult or even paid (no video tutorials though). python.org seems to have good tutorial with lots of examples.

Comment: @amrutrajGore Accepting should work. Don't know what resource to suggest, as I learned Python from here and there years ago, but I think python.org's tutorial is good, yes.

Comment: You can also find a list of good tutorials (including the official one) at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F